# Mpesa object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I would like to update the first item in the database each time a user clicks on a button but I keep getting the error every time, any assistance would be appreciated, below is the snippet.

```
Mpesa.objects.filter(Paid_user=self.request.user, Completed=False).first().update(Completed=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get first instance from filter result so model instances does not have update method. if you always have first object then instead of doing that, try to use instance `save` method;

```
instance = Mpesa.objects.filter(Paid_user=self.request.user, Completed=False).first()
instance.Completed = True
instance.save(update_fields=["Completed"])
```